# Make a table column as wide as its content

Tags: html, css

I usually use "width: 1px" to make a table column adapt to its content. Feels a bit hacky. Is there a more elegant way?

Here is an example:

```css
td {
  background: orange;
}

tr:nth-child(1n+2) td:first-of-type {
  width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=2>This is a long text that makes the table wide.<br> The left column should be as small as possible.</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Joe</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Age </td>
    <td>30</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>City</td>
    <td>New York</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: don't set a width I think should work? Or use the auto value

Comment: I don't understand what is wrong with your current code

Comment: width:0 or 1px is not hacky when it is about table-layout, it will expand to fit the widest content. It is the typical table behavior: shrink/expand according to content it holds. Width or height means min-width or min-height when about table. width can de fixed .. if table-layout is set to fixed. nothing can be done about height. it will grow as mauch as needed

Answer (score 0):

This could be another way to do it. It may seems a bit less 'hacky' as it tells the second `td` to take as much space as possible.

```css
td, th
{
  background: orange;
}



tr:nth-child(1n+2) td:first-of-type
{
 white-space: nowrap;
}

tr:nth-child(1n) td:last-of-type
{
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr><td colspan=2>This is a long text that makes the table wide.<br>
                  The left column should be as small as possible.</td></tr>
<tr><td>Name test</td><td>Joe</td></tr>
<tr><td>Age </td><td>30</td></tr>
<tr><td>City</td><td>New York</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: That changes the width of the table.